Can a Linux MDRAID be transferred to a different controller on the same system?
I have a Linux server with a 4-disk mdraid array controlled by an HBA (LSI SAS9300-8i) - if I relocate the disks to an external JBOD enclosure controlled by a different HBA (Broadcom SAS3008), will the system still recognize the array? Running Fedora Server 40.

Almost certainly. I personally haven't tried this with SAS disks, but it worked perfectly with SATA drives.
